# display xml contents in to a listview in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms

Ihave an xml file  sample.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DataSchema xmlns="http://tempuri.org/DataSchema.xsd">
  <ManagedObject>
    <Label>sam</Label>
    <Owner>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Owner>   
    <ClassID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000008</ClassID>
    <DefaultApp>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</DefaultApp>
    <Name>rvi</Name>
    <version>9.6</version>
  </ManagedObject>
</DataSchema>
```

i need to display 9.6 (9.6) from above xml file to the listview.I started a new windowform application. i added listview named "_listview" put its view as a "detail" mode.I added a column
there named _version
Can you give me the code to display version number in the listview column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your XML file will have always this structre you can use simply:

```
        string version = "";
        int n = 0;

        using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
        {
            ds.ReadXml(@"sample.xml");
            if(ds.Tables.Contains("ManagedObject") 
               && ds.Tables["ManagedObject"].Rows.Count > n)
            {
                ver = ds.Tables["ManagedObject"].Rows[n]["version"].ToString();
            }
        }
```

to get the n-th `ManagedObject` version.

in your case you have only 1, so `n = 0`.

if you want to add "version" as an item that will appear in the first column of the listview:

```
        listView1.Items.Add(version);
```

if "version" is to be added to an existing item in a secondary column use:

```
        listview1.Items[n].SubItems.Add(version);
```

you can look [here](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/10/28/listview.html) for further details.

Comment: Can you give me the complete code up to listview from the information i gave in my question that will be good for me like begginner

Comment: as per the logic it will work,,but how to show in listview something _listview.items.add like that

Comment: i got it sorry to disturb u,,_listview.Items.Add(version); will give

Comment: i posted one more answer najmeddine,, can you check it,,it will also work

Answer (score 0):

this will also work fine

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"F:\xml\sample.xml");
        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("sam", "http://tempuri.org/DataSchema.xsd");
        XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode(
            "/sam:DataSchema/sam:ManagedObject/sam:version", nsmgr);
        string version = node == null ? null : node.InnerText;

        _listview.Items.Add(version);
```